# Get notified when a shared Google Keep note is being updated?

Tags: collaboration, google-keep

I have some notes in [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com/) with collaborators.

How, if possible, can I get some kind of notification when such note is being updated by someone else?

Also third party solutions are fine, since I don't think it's possible just with Google Keep.

Comment: Has this been solved in later editions of google keep?

Comment: @DarrynBrisdaz Not that I've noticed